# Find intervals between elements of a list

Tags: list-manipulation

If I have a list:

```
{a,b,c,d,e,f}
```

Is there a function that allows me to easily construct a list that shows the intervals between elements:

```
{b-a,c-b,d-c,e-d,f-e}
```

I know I can shift the list then subtract (like below), but I am not sure whether there is a single function that would allow me to do it:

```
{a,b,c,d,e,f,0}-{0,a,b,c,d,e,f}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use `Differences`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!

Comment: `Differences[L]` is fine, as @MarcoB says; but for top speed I was surprised to find that `Rest[L]-Most[L]` is a bit faster.

Answer (score 5):

As @MarcoB says, `Differences` is the canonical way to go:

```
L = Sort@RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10^7];
d1 = Differences[L]; // RepeatedTiming // First
(* 0.20 *)
```

`Rest-Most` is twice as fast though, which I find very strange:

```
d2 = Rest[L] - Most[L]; // RepeatedTiming // First
(* 0.090 *)
```

`BlockMap` is a terrible idea:

```
d3 = BlockMap[#[[2]] - #[[1]] &, L, 2, 1]; // RepeatedTiming // First
(* 4.60 *)
```

All methods agree on the result though:

```
d1 == d2 == d3
(* True *)
```

Comment: The nice thing about `Differences` is the ease in using the second parameter to get differences of differences, and so on (wonder if the Rest/Most approach still holds out as better in that  case).

Comment: @MikeY yes it's still faster: `Differences[L, 2]` takes 0.36 seconds and `L[[3 ;;]] + L[[;; -3]] - 2 L[[2 ;; -2]]` takes only 0.25 seconds.